# Place arrow in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I want to place an arrow to indicate a remarkability in pgfplots.
For now, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.east)]
        \begin{axis}

           \addplot [only marks,thick,mark=x,mark size=4, color=red, mark size=6pt] coordinates {(-2,0) (0,0)};
           \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>};}}] coordinates {(-2,0) (-1,0)};
           \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>};}}] coordinates {(0,0) (-1,0)};
           \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>};}}] coordinates {(-1,0) (-1,-4)};
           \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>};}}] coordinates {(-1,0) (-1,4)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want it to add an arrow which can point to the cross to indicate something.

[image: the desired arrow]

Comment: Can you please make a compilable minimal working example which includes all libraries and packages necessary to compile your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the axis coordinate system to draw inside the plot.

Inside the `axis` environment, the units for coordinates are different, so that `(1,1)` is bound to the units of the axes and does not mean `(1cm,1cm)` like it is outside the `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.east)]
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [only marks,thick,mark=x,mark size=4, color=red, mark size=6pt] coordinates {(-2,0) (0,0)};
            \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>}}}] coordinates {(-2,0) (-1,0)};
            \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.85 with {\arrow{>}}}] coordinates {(0,0) (-1,0)};
            \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}] coordinates {(-1,0) (-1,-4)};
            \addplot [blue,thick,postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}] coordinates {(-1,0) (-1,4)};

            \draw[<-, red, thick, shorten <=10pt] (-2,0) -- ++(1cm,1cm) node[above] {$K = 1$};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also show me how to add the text next to this arrow?

Comment: Minor corrections - There should not be a `;` in `\arrow{>};`. `axis cs:` is the default coordinate system since PGFPlots 1.11, so there is no need to write it explicitly.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thanks! Corrected and edited according to your suggestions.